# How to install Cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cassandra

I want to install Cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm not sure which version to use. How to find the right Cassandra version for 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is written in Java, so it could be used with different distributions that have correct version of Java (Java 8 - oracle or openjdk).  If you're just starting, then you need to take latest released version: 3.11.3 (see [this article](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-3-11-x-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) for full instructions on setup) - add following source:

```
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main
```

and then install `cassandra` package, plus you need to install Python 2.7 - that's standard `python` package.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra distributed database is a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. The current stable version of the cassandra snap package is 3.7 and the edge version is 3.10-SNAPSHOT. To install cassandra run this command:

```
sudo snap install cassandra   
sudo snap connect cassandra:mount-observe
```

The cassandra snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.

You can check on the status of the cassandra service with:

```
systemctl status snap.cassandra.cassandra.service
```

If you were able to successfully start Cassandra, check the status of the cluster:

```
cassandra.nodetool status
```

In the output, `UN` means it's Up and Normal:

Set a custom configuration:

```
cat cassandra.yaml | sudo /snap/bin/cassandra.config-set cassandra.yaml
```

Commands:

- `cassandra.config-get`
- `cassandra.config-set`
- `cassandra.env-get`
- `cassandra.nodetool`